# Podio - creating API key

Tags: podio

I am working to develop an external application that will be used to update items in a Podio workspace via AJAX request.  However, I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding how to properly generate an API key...

In the API key generator, it asks for the 'Application name (displayed in stream byline)' - what exactly is meant by this?  Is 'Application' just an individual app in our workspace?  If so, is it possible to generate one API key for the entire workspace?  We will need to update items inside of many different apps (including apps that do not yet exist) from the same external application, and would probably prefer to not have to generate a unique key... it would be preferable for us to just have one API key with which we can update items in all of the apps in our workspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Application name` is not Podio individual app in your workspace, but rather name of application that you develop. So, in sentence:

> We will need to update items inside of many different apps (including
>   apps that do not yet exist) from the same external application ...

`Apps` - means Podio applications
`External application` - means application that you develop and you want to generate your API key for it, so it would be natural to name your API key in a way that you know which application is using it.

Comment: Thank you - that makes perfect sense to me now.